# PrimeNG: disable past time for datepicker

Tags: angular, momentjs, primeng

How to prevent timepicker from PrimeNG (https://github.com/primefaces/primeng) to display past times and start 20 min in advanced. I tired to set minDate to:

```
moment().add(20, 'm').toDate();
```

But this unfortunately stops working when I roll over 60 min (or 24 hours). It just stops at 00m or 0h.

Just to clarify: it is not about the calendar itself but rather the time functionality that you can get by setting [timeOnly]="true".

Comment: What's the best solution for that?

Comment: From the [doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar), you can disable specific dates and/or days but not hours or minutes...